# MightyText isn't working. Is it malware?

Tags: sms, malware, mightytext

I needed to send SMS from my PC because my hands finger's are fat then normal, which does not fit with smartphone small tiny buttons while i type large sentences, it takes me while to complete a small sentence.

So i searched and found this handy apps, i installed it, i got email i went to the web link but its not working

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.texty.sms

Is it a Trojan horse, malware or its trusted apps?

EDIT: this is the email

```
Welcome to MightyText!

Hi - Thanks for signing up with MightyText. You've joined over 1 Million people who use MightyText to text from their computer or tablet, using their Android phone number. To get you started, we've started syncing some recent text messages from your phone to MightyText. 

NOTE: You will still get SMS text messages on your phone as you normally would, and when texting on your phone you can keep using the same SMS texting app you've been using. 


Getting started - SMS from your computer now

To start texting from your computer, see instructions for your browser:

Google Chrome:

1 - Start Google Chrome browser, and install the MightyText Chrome Extension
2 - Launch the MightyText Web App on your computer: https://mightytext.net/app

Firefox:

1 - Install this third party Firefox Add-on to get notifications. (Firefox doesn't support HTML Notifications natively)
2 - NOTE: For Firefox Mac users only -- you'll also need to install Growl Notifications for Mac. Download free version of Growl here.
3 - Launch the MightyText Web App on your computer: https://mightytext.net/app

Internet Explorer, Safari, Opera

Follow the steps here 


SMS from your Android Tablet

On your tablet, install using this link or search for mightytext on the Google Play Store from your tablet.

Any questions? Just reply to this email.

thank you and happy texting,

The MightyText Team
 follow us on Twitter | MightyText on Facebook
```

Comment: Why would you assume it's malware just because you can't get it working? If you describe fully what steps you took and what happened, someone might be able to help you out.

Comment: See my EDIT please, i got email saying i can open the page `mightytext.net/app` but it does not open anything after installing all. Does it mean its stealing all my information now?

Comment: So what happens when you go to that page?

Comment: When i go to that page, its like taking forever to open and then Google chrome say failed to open the page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[According to the official Twitter feed](https://twitter.com/MightyText/status/453428505443721216), their website is having problems right now. Try it again later.

MightyText is a reputable piece of software, so while we can't say for sure what they're doing with your information (like any other closed-source software), you shouldn't assume it's malware just because it's not working as it should.

See also [this Venn diagram illustrating the situation:
[image: Virus Venn diagram]](https://xkcd.com/1180/)

Comment: It was strange for me, cause just today was my 1st day and 1st time try and 1st time it did not worked. Now it seems to be working. My 1st experience and 1st impression was that i was infected cause it did not worked. But now i am feeling comfortable with it. Thank you